# Foundation5 reveal not firing when called from javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, zurb-foundation

Just updated Zurb's Foundation4 to 5 and one of the things I've noticed is that I can't get the reveal to work like how I used to with version 4.

I've started from scratch with a fresh download of the framework and still can't seem to get the reveal to work, here's the following code I've got.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.0.2/css/foundation.min.css" />
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.7.0/modernizr.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Reveal Test</h1>
    <p><a href="/server.php?id=1234" data-reveal-id="myModal1" data-reveal-ajax="true">Load via a href ajax (calling /server.php) - works!</a></p>
    <p><a id="fire-via-js">Load via javascript</a></p>

    <div id="myModal1" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal><a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a></div>
    <div id="myModal2" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal><a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a></div>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.0.2/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
      $(document).ready(function() {

            // url with custom callbacks
            $('#fire-via-js').click(function() {
                $('#myModal2').foundation('reveal', 'open', {
                    url: '/server.php?id=5678',
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('modal data loaded');
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('failed loading modal');
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

...it calls the server.php file which is just this...

```
<?php

echo "hello world...<br />";

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    echo "got the id : ". $_GET['id'] ."<br />";
}
```

According to the docs, "Ajax-based Reveal modals can also be opened via JavaScript:" which is fine as it's just how it used to work, but when I try and load it through javascript, it just will not return the output from the php file into the modal.

Maybe I'm missing something basic, been porting over the old calls to the new stuff now for a few hours so if it's a silly miss, it'd be great to have a pointer!

Comment: Ah, apparently this is a known issue on the latest release of the framework.

Comment: Yes, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3444). Here is a [fix](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/pull/3850)

Answer (score 0):

The Latest release of Foundation 5 has resolved this issue as noted by Damien. Downloaded and checked on the 25/02/2014